# AWS QuickSight Embedding CLI error - aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, embedding, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to embed a QuickSight Dashboard and am following the current steps.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/embed-interactive-dashboards-in-your-application-with-amazon-quicksight/

I'm at step 3 and able to assume the role and,

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="access_key_from_assume_role"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="secret_key_from_assume_role "
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="session_token_from_assume_role"
```

However when I try and do the next step of calling "aws quicksight ..." from the next part I'm getting the following error,

> aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

I've installed pip and made sure the command line text matches with correct details.

Has anyone experienced this or has any ideas why aws quicksight command wouldn't be working in the CLI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check AWS CLI version:

```
aws --version
```

It looks like the AWS CLI needs update.
To upgrade an existing AWS CLI installation, use the `--upgrade` option:

```
pip install --upgrade awscli
```

If you have pip3 then.

```
pip3 install --upgrade awscli
```

or

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade awscli
```

Also remember that `aws sts assume-role --role-arn` has expiry token, to need to run this command again to get `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` to continue.
What I did was I, I prepared a tempprofile for these credentials and used this profile in next `aws quicksight` commands.
e.g

```
aws configure set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID XXXXXXX --profile tempprofile
aws configure set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY XXXXXXXX--profile tempprofile
aws configure set AWS_SESSION_TOKEN XXXXXXX --profile tempprofile
```

In my case also I set

```
aws configure set REGION ap-southeast-2 --profile tempprofile
```

and then in next `aws quicksight` commands use `--profile tempprofile`